# Call swagger API in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, swagger, postman, restsharp

I have an API for getting data that is created in Swagger. I Only have an base URL and an username, password and a token for that. When I go to the URL it will go to a login page and after login, We can access a list of APIs and get data from that.

Now I need that to be done in C# using restsharp. So that I can get the result in JSON and can update the values to DB.

This is my code which I used in C#

```
var restClient = new RestClient("https://v3.fusesport.com/api/events/")
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("xxxxx", "xxxxx")
        };
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This is getting an connection closed error.

I tried the API in postman app in chrome, it is getting the below error.

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

This is the screenshot of postman call with token 
[Postman with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3hWr.png)

This is the screenshot of postman call with basic authentication
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxT6c.png)

Can you help me what I am doing wrong. I think the API is using session based authentication.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this link http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/restsharp-http-basic-authentication. You need to add username and password to your restsharp client

Comment: I have used username and password too still it says "Authentication credentials were not provided". Edited my code.

Comment: If you are sending username and password, request method should be POST not GET. Try it with POST method.

Comment: Tried with POST, no use. I think it is something to do with the swagger API.

Answer (score 0):

I think your headers are incorrect. Instead of

```
request.AddHeader("Token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

try adding

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b");
```

Comment: According to the `WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"` response header seen in https://v3.fusesport.com/api/events/ it should be `JWT xxxxx` and not `Token xxxxx`.